# Defining suitable predicate and function symbols.

Tags: predicate-logic

I am really struggling to build intuition with regards to how to do this sort of question.

The abstract:
A graph is a set (whose elements are called nodes) together with a symmetric relation on that set (related nodes are said to have an edge between them). A binary tree is a graph which has a distinguished node, called the root, which is connected to two other (distinct) nodes, and every other node is connected to three distinct nodes or one (distinct) node.

The question:
How would I define a suitable set of predicate symbols and function symbols together with their arities that give rise to a first order language suitable for specifying binary trees?

Comment: A domain for the variables dentong the *vertex* and a binary relation $E$ such that $E(x,y)$ holds if the two vertex $x,y$ are connected by and *edge*.

Comment: How would I define the predicate and function symbols?

Comment: the predicate symbol for "$x$ and $y$ connected by an edge" is as per @MauroALLEGRANZA described. I do not think you need any function symbols to specify a binary tree.

Comment: oh ok, its just the question was 4 marks

Comment: I really do not understand this topic, what is the intuition to get that answer?  What is the domain for the variables denoting the vertex?

Comment: The question asks for function symbols though as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *graph* is a pair $\mathcal G = (V,E)$ where $V$ is a set of elements called *vertices* (or *nodes*) and $E$ is an anti-reflexive and symmetric binary relation on $V$ called the edge relation.

This means that the relation $E$ must satisfy the following axioms :

> $\forall x \lnot E(x,x)$

meaning that there is no *edge* "looping" on a single vertice (this is *anti-reflexivity*), and :

> $\forall x \forall y (E(x,y) \rightarrow E(y,x))$

meaning that if there is and edge connecting the vertices $x$ and $y$, the same edge connects $y$ and $x$ (this is *symmetry*).

---

For a *binary tree* we can try adding to the above language an individual *constant* $r$ for the *root* and a unary function symbol : $f$ for the "father" of a node.

They have to satisfy the following axioms :

> $\forall x (x \ne r \rightarrow \exists y (x = f(r)))$
>
> $\forall x \forall y \forall z(E(x,y) \land E(x,z) \rightarrow (x=f(y) \land x=f(z)))$.

Comment: Hey I am not allowed to post anymore questions today because I have reached my 24 hour limit therefore I will ask you here. In sequent calculus, how do you know whether to use left inference rules or right inference rules?

Comment: @user204450 - in sequent calculus working bottom-up (i.e. in a root-first proof search) the R rules give as a conclusion a sequent with the principal formula, i.e., the formula with the
connective of the rule, at right of the derivability relation symbol ($\vdash$); the L rules with the principal formula at left.

Comment: Thanks, what about cut rule? Where does the extra A come from in the cut rule theorem?

Comment: so how does the formula change in relation to using the right or left inference rules?